# tinymce not submitting content started with space

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, tinymce

I am using tinymce html editor in my form. I am getting content value by 
tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();
Using ajax to submit values to server.
Issue is when there is empty space at start in editor it send only

to server when type is "POST", but if set type to GET then it send full content correctly. My code is below

```
var msg = tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();
var data = "typ=updat_sig&at=qewrasf&msg=" + msg;
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            typ: "updat_sig",
            url: baseURL,
            data: data,

            success: function (data) {

            },

            dataType: "JSON"
        });
```

Please help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode it before sending:

```
var msg = tinymce.get('elm1').getContent();
msg = encodeURIComponent(msg);
```